# How to match first 6 characters of a cell instead of the whole cell

Tags: excel, vba, match

Focusing on:

`rows = w2.Columns("A:A").Find(What:=aCell, LookAt:=xlWhole).Row`

Instead of looking at the whole cell to match (xlwhole), I'm trying to only match the first 6 characters of the cell. I've looked into xlpart and a few other options but have been unsuccessful.

```
Sub test()
Dim aCell
Dim A, B As Long, rows As Long
Dim w1, w2 As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range

Set w1 = Workbooks("Book1").Sheets("Sheet1")
Set w2 = Workbooks("Book2").Sheets("Sheet1")

A = w1.Cells(w1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
B = w2.Cells(w2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For Each aCell In w1.Range("A2:A" & A)
On Error Resume Next
rows = w2.Columns("A:A").Find(What:=aCell, LookAt:=xlWhole).Row
On Error GoTo 0

If rows = 0 Then

Else
    w2.Range("B" & rows).Value = aCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
End If
rows = 0
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Find` supports wildcards `*`. Use `Left$` to get the first 6 characters of the cell value.

```
For Each aCell In w1.Range("A2:A" & A)
   Dim rng As Range
   Set rng = w2.Columns("A:A").Find(What:=Left$(aCell.Value, 6) & "*", LookAt:=xlWhole)

   ' First test if the find succeeded
   If Not rng Is Nothing Then
       rng.Offset(,1).Value = aCell.Offset(,1).Value
   End If
Next
```

Comment: Ah. If the values in `w2` are just the 6 characters to be matched, then you don't need the `& "*"`. If you want to match something like `abcdef123` to `abcdef456`, then keep the wildcard.

Comment: I might create a second question thread for this... looking at the above code, any idea how I could loop the macro so if there are multiple matches of Column A to Column B it continue to fill out column B with the data from column A?

Comment: You can use [`FindNext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.findnext) to find the next match, using a loop. Though personally I'd just use two `Variant` arrays at that point and loop over the arrays to find a match, instead of using `Find`/`FindNext`. Depends on how many rows there are.

Comment: There would be quite a few rows. I'll have to look into Variant arrays, not too sure how to set that up.

Comment: [This](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx) is a good explanation/start. If you don't go the array route, there are examples here on SO of how to set up a `Find`/`FindNext` loop.